# Can you teach an old human new tricks?

Tags: learning, aging

I'm not sure if this is on topic here, but, there's a common phrase 'You can't teach an old dog new tricks'.

This is commonly used as an observation about human behaviour, in that you can expect people to continue behaving they way they have behaved in the past. But the phrase is specifically derived from the idea that if a dog isn't trained by the time its old, it's very difficult to then train it.

The question is - is there good data available about the comparative  neuroplasticity of dogs, and other animals, and humans?

Comment: https://mindhacks.com/2010/06/07/neuroplasticity-is-a-dirty-word/

Comment: And yeah there are some cross-species studies aging and training e.g. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4264379/ But your question whether "is there good data available" is just soliciting opinion and not even about a well-circumscribed topic.